# how can i diplay password expiry in x days notification for Azure b2c users?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

is that possible to display password expiry notification to b2c users when they login to the application
example : your password ids going to expire in 10 days, something like that(custom policies)
Expecting :password expiry notification for b2c users

Answer (score 0):

You could use this [sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/force-password-reset-after-90-days) as a guide to associate a date with the password.

Then, check every time they log in.

You can use [this](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/adding-extra-text-to-a-self-asserted-page-in-azure-ad-b2c-8e5e69f0387d) to display the message. This adds the text as an input field.

**Note**: The link is to my blog.